Camelot won't import even though its in sys.path
Having a nightmare installing camelot-py for jupyter notebook
Tried installing with pip inside the notebook, then through powershell, then through Anaconda miniconda terminal.
The package finally installs with powershell, pip list shows it while in the powershell.
Go to the notebook, pip list doesnt show camelot, but it shows that camelot is in the sys.path, cant import camelot
Also conda info --envs in powershell shows same location for environment as sys.prefix in notebook - insane!!
please help

Sounds like you might have two different installations of python on your computer.

Please edit the question and show the output of this command pip show camelot-py and also the output of this code import sys; print(sys.path)

You aren't specific about how you are installing inside the notebook. Are you using the magic %pip install command? You may want to see the bottom of here for more about that. Maybe more troubling though is later you mention Anaconda/miniconda. If you went Anaconda/conda route than that became your primary package manager and you should avoid using pip. Did you try the magic install %conda install conda-forge::camelot-py (based on https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/camelot-py) in the running notebook so it installs to correct environment?

seems like the module is in the root python site-packages folder but not in the site-packages for the environment I created - hoping this fixes it

Hoping what fixes it? This isn't a clear solution that would help others. (In fact, 'hoping this fixes it' indicates you aren't sure it is a solution yet.) Please improve that or remove this and add it as update to your post.
